# MongoDB speed when returning last document

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a web app with tons of documents. User can enter id (valid MongoId / ObjectId), but if user doesn't enter it I have to retrieve object with last id:

I'm concerned about speed for searching last object. I'm currently doing it like this:

```
db.docs.find({"status": 1}).sort({"_id": -1}).limit(1);
//Or in php:
$docs->find(array('status' => 1))->sort(array('_id' => -1))->limit(1)->getNext();
```

Isn't this a bit slow? First is looking for all docs with status 1 then sort them and limit then. Is there any better way for getting last document with status 1?

Answer (score 2):

To make this performant you'd likely need to add an index on `{ status: 1, _id: -1 }`.

You can also use `findOne` instead of find with a limit to simplify the syntax:

```
db.docs.findOne({"status": 1}).sort({"_id": -1});
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps just store another value in another table, or in an in-memory cache perhaps, indicating the highest id value the system has as status=1.  It would require a small bit of logic to be added when inserting/updating objects in the database, to compare the id value of objects with status=1 against the current cached id value, updating if the value is higher. You could then access the latest file directly using this cached value.

It is a little clunky, but would probably perform much better than the `find.sort.limit` operation you are currently doing as your number of objects grows.